# Plot multiple runs of gbm.step() in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gbm

I have run a set of 100 runs of `gbm.step` to account for the stochasticity component of the analysis, which provides slightly different results for each BRT model, and consequently estimate the range (minimum and maximum values) for the fitted functions.
I want to plot these results in a plot like this one:

[image: plot 100 gbm runs]

Reproducible example:

```
data(iris)
mod2<-list()
for(i in 1:100){
  mod2[[i]]<-gbm.step(data=iris, gbm.x = 3:4, gbm.y = 1,
                   family = "gaussian", tree.complexity = 4,
                   learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.5, tolerance.method = "fixed")
}
gbm.plot(mod2[[1]],common.scale=F,smooth=T,write.title = FALSE, plot.layout = c(1,2))
```

This is a plot of one of the 100 models. I want one like the image above.

Is there any function that takes my 100 models and plot it like this? If not, what is the best approach to take in ggplot?

Comment: Can you provide a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) of your problem?

Comment: Here is the example. I can plot one model, but I have no idea on how to plot the vales of the mean, min and max values of the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try something like this:

```
data(iris)
mod2<-list()
for(i in 1:20){
  mod2[[i]]<-gbm.step(data=iris,
  gbm.x = 3:4, gbm.y = 1,
  family = "gaussian", tree.complexity = 4,
  learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.5, tolerance.method = "fixed")
}
```

And we take some relevant parts out of gbm.plot, to make a pretty primitive function for 1 predictor, to get the x and y values:

```
getVar = function(gbm.object,predictor_of_interest){
gbm.call <- gbm.object$gbm.call
gbm.x <- gbm.call$gbm.x
pred.names <- gbm.call$predictor.names
response.name <- gbm.call$response.name
data <- gbm.call$dataframe
k <- match(predictor_of_interest, pred.names)
var.name <- gbm.call$predictor.names[k]
pred.data <- data[, gbm.call$gbm.x[k]]
response.matrix <- gbm::plot.gbm(gbm.object, k, return.grid = TRUE)
data.frame(predictors = response.matrix[, 1],
responses = response.matrix[, 2] - mean(response.matrix[,2])
)
}
```

Then we iterate through the list of models, collect data:

```
library(ggplot2)
da = lapply(1:length(mod2),function(i){
data.frame(getVar(mod2[[i]],"Petal.Length"),model=i)})
da = do.call(rbind,da)
```

We can plot all the lines, specifying `group` in the `aes`:

```
ggplot(da,aes(x=predictors,y=responses,group=model)) + 
geom_line(alpha=0.4) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or min,max,mean as you mentioned using stat_summary, without the group:

```
ggplot(da,aes(x=predictors,y=responses)) +
stat_summary(geom="ribbon",fun.ymin="min",fun.ymax="max",alpha=0.3) +
stat_summary(geom="line",fun.y="mean")+theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf, you saved me a lot of work! Do you know how can I plot the response in the original scale, instead of the estimates?

Comment: Hi @JMarcelino, i need to be awfk, in the function above, last line responses = response.matrix[, 2] - mean(response.matrix[,2]); you do responses = response.matrix[, 2] , and it should work.. maybe you try and if it doesn't work I can look into it :)

Comment: Awesome, you have been a big help these days! Thank you!

Comment: I have now seen that your function is using plot.gbm(). I thought it was plotting marginal effects when the remaining variables are held at their average, and not integrating the other variables.. Is there a workaround so the other variables are held on their average? Thanks

Comment: Hmmm i don't quite get your question, how would you hold other variables at their average? You basically do a prediction right and have the other variables at a constan mean? how different will it be from this marginal plot?

Comment: I guess my problem is: I don't understand why gbm.plot(), gbm.plot.fits() and plot.gbm() give different results. I have to make a new question about it.